# should I free the c pointer after bridge cast (objective c)?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Wondering if I should free "size" pointer below?

```
NSSize *size = (__bridge NSSize*)[track attributeForKey:QTTrackDimensionsAttribute];
...
free(size);
```

Comment: No, from where did you get the idea? But that method doesn't even return `NSSize`. It returns an `NSValue` object that **wraps** an `NSSize`. So what you have is wrong either way.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from Apple documentation **Transitioning to ARC Release Notes**

> __bridge transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.

It works the same as standard cast. You don't use free, ARC will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling have a return type of `(id)`.
So there is no `C pointer` involve here, which make `free(size)` just plain wrong and the `__bridge` cast is not needed also because `id` is already an Object and ARC will know what to do with it.

Depending on the Key you are passing the type of the return object will vary, refer to the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Track_Attributes) to get the exact class type you will be getting.